# gtk spin button size change via css styling - works only with older GTK release?

Tags: css, button, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to downsize GTK widgets by reducing the padding. The following works in Ubuntu 16.04 but not in later releases. In 17.04 and 17.10 the css styling has no effect on spin buttons. Other buttons are restyled as expected.

file widgets.css

```
* {
   padding: 1px 1px;
}
button {
   padding: 0px 3px;
}
entry {
   padding: 0px 2px;
}
```

What needs to change to make it work with later GTK releases?

Answer (score 1):

For the current GTK release, check the ["CSS Nodes" section of the documentation for `GtkSpinButton`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSpinButton.html#GtkSpinButton.description) to see the hierarchy of nodes that you can apply CSS to. It looks like you might need to write a CSS rule for `spinbutton`.

Comment: Thanks. There is no padding property for 'spinbutton'. 'spinbutton' contains 'entry', also with no padding. Since different themes and different GTK releases behave differently, I will not try to modify spinbuttons.

Comment: @MichaelCornelison Did you try it? `padding` is a general CSS property, so it **is** available for any widget with proper CSS nodes (i.e. all but a few stragglers in GTK 3). Were you looking at widget properties or style properties instead? That's not the right place. Widget docs tell you about nodes. To see CSS properties you can use, use the [CSS Properties documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html). `spinbutton { padding: 10px; }` does work. `padding` alone might not do what you want - i.e. you might need to do more to counter the theme - but it works.